# Getting an array with lengths of words from a sentence -javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will tell me how long the longest word in a sentence is. My approach is to split the sentence into strings of words. I now have an array of strings. My problem is that I want to use this array to get another array of numbers i.e. the length of each word. How do I do this? My code is as below but I keep getting null.

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var split = str.split(" ");
  for (j = 0; j < split.length; j++)
  var wordCount = split[j].length;
  var lengths = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < wordCount.length; i++) {
    lengths.push(i);
  }

  return Math.max(...lengths);
}
```

Comment: If you want to turn one list/array into another (you want to turn a list of words into a list of lengths), and the resulting list is the same length as the original list, use the `map` function. `map` takes a list, applies a function to each element, and returns the resulting list.

Comment: if it is a sentence, it may contain punctuation. Then your split(" ") is not going to work. I think your question is to find the length of the longest word in a list of words. And you should always try to avoid using keyword/function name as your variable name such as the split.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to loop through all the words you can already find the max (longest) word in your input array.

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var split = str.split(" ");
  var maxLength = 0;
  var longestWord = "";  // If no word is found "".length will return 0
  var len = split.length;
  for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
  {
    if (split[j].length > maxLength)
    {
        longestWord = split[j];
        maxLength = split[j].length;
    }
  }

  return longestWord;
}
```

And the returned value `.length` to get the length (or `return maxLength` if you so desire).

Note depending on your application punctuation might interfere with your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some comments about the mistakes in your code

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {

  // better use .split(/\s+/) instead to remove trailing space in the middle of sentence
  var split = str.split(" ");
  
  // this for loop is redundant, you have to wrap the code that you want to loop with curly brackets.
  for (j = 0; j < split.length; j++)
  
  // the value of j would be the length of split array.
  var wordCount = split[j].length;
  var lengths = [];
  
  // since wordCount.length is undefined, so loop never gets excuted and your lengths array would be empty. 
  for (var i = 0; i < wordCount.length; i++) {
    lengths.push(i);
  }
  
  // doing Math.max on empty array will return -Infinity
  return Math.max(...lengths);
}

findLongestWord('hello there mate')
```

Below are my solutions. There are also more ways of doing what you want to do.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  // trim trailing white space.
  var split = str.trim().split(/\s+/);
  var lengths = [];
  
  // loop through array of words
  for (j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
  
    // check the length of current words
    var wordCount = split[j].length;
    lengths.push(wordCount);
  }
  
  return Math.max(...lengths);
}

const sentence = 'hello its a me mariooooooo';

console.log(findLongestWord(sentence))

// one liner - using reduce function
const findLongestWord2 = (str) => str.trim().split(/\s+/).reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a.length : b.length, -Infinity);

console.log(findLongestWord2(sentence))

// less efficient but shorter - using sort
const findLongestWord3 = (str) => str.trim().split(/\s+/).sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length).pop().length;

console.log(findLongestWord3(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes an array of words and transforms it into an array of each word's length.

```
function multi(arr) {
     var newarr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      newarr.push( arr[i].length);
  }
  return newarr;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use var to create j in the first for loop like you did for the second for loop with i.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using the `.map()` method. You map the array of strings into an array of word lengths, and then return the `Math.max()` of the array of lengths, like so:

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  // map words into array of each word's length, grab highest #
  return Math.max(...str.split(" ").map(str => str.length));
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```